# User draws a box, captures an image, then outputs text extracted from image. How do I go about doing this?

Tags: javascript, c#, image, text, screenshot

Okay with either c# or JS how would I go about this?

I want to let the user draw a box using click and drag over their screen (essentially taking a screen shot) and then extract the text from it. From there (for now) just output the text to console or text file.

Hopefully this is specific enough. Anyone have experience with this before?

My background is mostly in c# with .NET windows forms. So if you could be as detailed as possible with your help I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Looks like a project, sorry to say that we are not providing such services

Comment: @un-lucky sorry, where can I go to get help with this? My bad man

Comment: @JaromandaX my bad meant to say JS